# Read csv file using read.csv() without losing milliseconds

Tags: r, csv, datetime, timestamp

I have a csv file with a timestamp column. The timestamps are in the format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS4`  that is there is a milliseconds value also of 4 digits. When i read this csv using `read.csv()` I do not get the milliseconds but only till seconds in character format. How can I read the milliseconds also ?
Edit to add requires data and code:
`mtc_data = read.csv(path/to/csv)`
[Notepad.pw link to data](https://notepad.pw/code/sm3i3tgvb)

Comment: Could you provide an excerpt of your .csv?

Comment: The code for the read.csv() call might also be useful so we could see what parameters are being used.

Comment: @jay.sf added csv data

Comment: @user2332849 added code used for reading the csv

Comment: I could not reproduce the truncating of the strings. read.csv() does not normally truncate the data if it is in character type. I think something else is going on.

Comment: @HarshitNagar Thanks, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading in with `read.csv` (where you may want to use option `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`) use `as.POSIXct` with the format string you already have. The miliseconds are internally stored. Using `strftime` you can display the miliseconds, the variable is no longer `"POSIXct"` format then, but `"character"`. It might be more safe to use `trimws` to get rid of unnecessary spaces after reading in.

```
dat <- read.csv("V:/R/_data/yourData.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
(x <- as.POSIXct(trimws(dat$timestamp), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"))
# [1] "2018-11-20 00:00:00 CET" "2018-11-20 00:00:05 CET" "2018-11-20 00:00:07 CET"

x2 <- strftime(x, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS6")
x2
# [1] "2018-11-20 00:00:00.000000" "2018-11-20 00:00:05.058399" "2018-11-20 00:00:07.540699"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specify "POSIXct" as the colClass for the datetime column when calling `read.csv` you preserve the time information, including milliseconds, as shown below.

```
# my_options <- options(digits.secs = 4) 
df <- read.csv(
  "data.csv"
  ,colClasses = c("POSIXct","factor")
  ,na.strings = c("")
)

print(
  format(df$timestamp[2], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS4') 
) # "2018-11-20 00:00:05.0583"
```

Specifying `options(digits.secs = 4)` is helpful to have millisecond display to four digits, but is not necessary to preserve the information (in this case at least). It can be useful to specify `na.strings` to handle missing values too. Note too that annoyingly POSIXct doesn't seem to handle [ISO standard dates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) with "T" separating the date and time by default: it will truncate the time information if it finds one, so if you have these you may need to replace the "T" with a space first.

See the `read.csv` docs [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/read.table).

For reference, the CSV file is:

```
"timestamp","execution"
2018-11-20 00:00:00.0000,"STOPPED"
2018-11-20 00:00:05.0584,"STOPPED"
2018-11-20 00:00:07.5407,"RUNNING"
```